# Save PDF with Shrine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

I'm trying to save pdf files with Shrine. Following Shrine [readme](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine), I'm attributing

`my_model.image = File.open('my_pdf.pdf')`

but that raises an error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xFE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

How can I acomplish this? There is a way to save binary files with Shrine?

Here is the uploader I'm using:

```
class DocumentUploader < Shrine
  plugin :logging
  plugin :validation_helpers
  plugin :determine_mime_type, analyzer: :mimemagic
  plugin :data_uri

  Attacher.validate do
    validate_max_size 20*1024*1024, message: "is too large (max is 20 MB)"
    validate_mime_type_inclusion %w[
      image/jpeg
      image/gif
      image/bmp
      image/png
      image/tiff
      application/pdf
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to open binary files in binary mode: `my_model.image = File.open('my_pdf.pdf', 'rb')`

Comment: also make sure your my_model.image can receive binary, if it's a database table and field that would be a blob

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like `try_encoding` to convert from `ASCII-8BIT` or others:

```
def try_encoding(new_value)
  if new_value.is_a? String
    begin
      # Try it as UTF-8 directly
      cleaned = new_value.dup.force_encoding('UTF-8')
      unless cleaned.valid_encoding?
        # Some of it might be old Windows code page
        cleaned = new_value.encode('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252')
      end

      new_value = cleaned
    rescue EncodingError
      # Force it to UTF-8, throwing out invalid bits
      new_value.encode!('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
    end

    new_value
  end
end
```